# how to open *.md file like a regular *.ipynb inside jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a folder with name DLearn containing lots of subfolders. Each subfolders contains a number of *.md files. when I open them inside jupyter notebook they rae opening as a one bid cell, which is very difficult to read and work with. Everything is markdown, even codes are not possible to run.
Navigating to my DLearn folder in the terminal, and run the `jupytext --set-formats md,ipynb **/*.md`  command to convert all the Markdown files to Jupyter Notebook files. They all changed in the extensions, however, once opening any *ipynb I still have a big markdown cell. How to have a regular cell-wise notebook?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Markdown` files are not properly formatted for `jupyter-notebook`. When you use `jupytext` it just changes the file format.

for example this is a properly formatted file:

```
<!-- #region -->
# This is a Markdown cell

Here's some text in the Markdown cell.
<!-- #endregion -->

<!-- #region code -->
print("This is a code cell")
<!-- #endregion -->
```

modify your file accordingly then apply `jupytext --to ipynb <your_file.md>` now re open your file in `jupyter-notebook`